# convert audio file into float array

Tags: android, audio-recording

i m making an application based on voice modulation.

i got success to record and play audio file using media recorder:

**now i want to convert my audio file(.3gp) in float array. i have tried a lot but still i dont get any proper solution :**

can somebody tell me how to achieve this

my code for recording is

```
 mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
           mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
           if (audiofile == null) {
                  File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                  try { 

                      audiofile = File.createTempFile("Record", ".3gp", sampleDir);


                  } 
                  catch (IOException e)
                  {
                      Log.e("abc","sdcard access error");
                      return;
                  }
          }

           mr.prepare();
            mr.start();
```